# Character ^ in java string which I want to remove

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I want to remove ^ character from my string but it is not working. I have used the replaceAll method but it still not working.

```
String str = "^\"^s^h^u^b^h^a^m\"^:";
    str=str.replaceAll("^", "");
    System.out.println(str);
```

And I am getting this output.

```
^"^s^h^u^b^h^a^m"^:
```

Comment: `^` is a regex _metacharacter_ and must be escaped if you want to specify its literal value.  Use: `str.replaceAll("\\^", "")`

Comment: Or just use `str.replace("^", "")` unless you actually *want* regular expression matching...